# Array with-in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been beating my head on my desk since 9am and with all the searching I did, I'm still not getting the results I need. What I have is an array that is dynamically created using.

```
  array_push($this->product_info,
        $subline1,
        $subline2,
        $subcarving,
        $subpicture,
        $extra_cost,
        $subtotal);

  if(!empty($this->cart)){
    array_push($this->cart, $this->product_info);
  }
  else
  {
    $this->cart = $this->product_info;
  }
```

After being set the user can add another product or proceed to checkout. If they add another product I append the new array using array_push() as you can see. So now the array has more that 1 array. I want to be able to just grab the just two elements from each array. So I wrote this:

```
$count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'][$i] as $key => $value){
            echo "This is element $i with key $key: $value<br />";      
        }
}
```

And this is what is outputted to the browser:

```
This is element 0 with key 0: VP1021-G
This is element 0 with key product_id: VP1021-G
This is element 0 with key 1: Pendant
This is element 0 with key product_type: Pendant
This is element 0 with key 2: Vertical
This is element 0 with key product_format: Vertical
This is element 0 with key 3: Goldtone
This is element 0 with key setting_color: Goldtone
This is element 0 with key 4: 125
This is element 0 with key price: 125
This is element 0 with key 5: N/A
This is element 0 with key 6: N/A
This is element 0 with key 7: Black and White
This is element 0 with key 8: 01_faces.jpg
This is element 0 with key 9: 0
This is element 0 with key 10: 125
This is element 1 with key 0: Array
```

I can grab what I want if I use this:

```
print_r($_SESSION['cart'][0][0]);
echo "<br /><br />";
print_r($_SESSION['cart'][1][0][0]);
```

but I wont be able to grab the rest of the array if there is more than 2.
Here are both functions:

```
#Process
function ProcBuildCameo(){
    global $session, $form;

    $retval = $session->BuildCameo($_POST['product_type'], $_POST['product_format'], $_POST['setting_color'], $_POST['carving_color'], $_POST['line1'], $_POST['line2'], $_FILES['picture']['name']);

    /* Submit order successful */
    if($retval == 0){
        $_SESSION['product_info'] = $session->product_info;
        if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
            $_SESSION['cart'] = $session->cart;
        }
        else{
            array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$session->cart);
        }

        //var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
        //die();
        $_SESSION['info'] = true;
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        header("Location: view_cameo.php");
        die();
    }
    /* Error found with form */
    else if($retval == 1){
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->GetErrorArray();
        header("Location: cameo.php");
        die();
    }
}
 #Session
 function BuildCameo($subtype, $subformat, $subsetting, $subcarving, $subline1, $subline2, $subpicture){
    global $mysql, $form;
    $extra_cost = 0;

    /* type error checking */
    $field = "product_type";
    if(!$subtype || strlen($subtype = trim($subtype)) == 0){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Product not checked!");
    }
    /* format error checking */
    $field = "product_format";
    if(!$subformat || strlen($subformat = trim($subformat)) == 0){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Format not checked!");
    }
    /* setting color error checking */
    $field = "setting_color";
    if(!$subsetting || strlen($subsetting = trim($subsetting)) == 0){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Setting color not checked!");
    }
    /* carving color error checking */
    $field = "carving_color";
    if(!$subcarving || strlen($subcarving = trim($subcarving)) == 0){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Carving color not checked!");
    }
    /* checks if line1 is empty */
    if(!$subline1 || strlen($subline1 = trim($subline1)) == 0){
        $subline1 = "N/A";
    }
    else{
        $extra_cost = 15;
    }
    /* checks if line2 is empty */
    if(!$subline2 || strlen($subline2 = trim($subline2)) == 0){
        $subline2 = "N/A";
    }
    else{
        $extra_cost = $extra_cost + 15;
    }
    $field = "picture";
    $valid = array('jpg','jpeg');
    if(!$subpicture || strlen($subpicture = trim($subpicture)) == 0){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Select a picture to upload!");
    }
    if(!in_array(end(explode('.',$subpicture)),$valid)){
        $form->SetError($field, "* Please upload jpg or jpeg files!");
    }
    /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if($form->num_errors > 0){
        return 1;  //Errors with form
    }
    else{
        if($mysql->GetProductInfo($subtype, $subformat, $subsetting)){
            $this->product_info = $mysql->GetProductInfo($subtype, $subformat, $subsetting);
            $subtotal = $this->product_info['price'] + $extra_cost;
            array_push($this->product_info, $subline1, $subline2, $subcarving, $subpicture, $extra_cost, $subtotal);
            if(!empty($this->cart)){
                array_push($this->cart, $this->product_info);
            }
            else{
                $this->cart = $this->product_info;
            }

            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"])){   
               /**
                * Give video file unique name 
                * and copy from temp folder
                * to videos folder
                */
                copy($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"],"pictures/" . $subpicture);

            }           
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not providing all the code necessary to solve this, how is `$this->cart` becoming part of `$_SESSION`?  Something not right how you append to the array

Comment: it is being set in a different page;

Comment: if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $session->cart;
   }
   else{
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$session->cart);
   }

Comment: so? Still missing code, there is no way to help you here if you don't show all the code in the process.

Comment: ok I will give you the whole function from the process and session files

Comment: It is not really clear what the question is at all. Maybe try rewording what you are asking.

Comment: What I mean is I have an array which will store more arrays.

Comment: In each array I will have a products info. What I want is to be able to grab the products id and the cost of the product for each product and display it to the user. So far I have been able to do it by referring to each array by index but if there is more than 1 or two this process will be useless.

Comment: Read everything you can find about PHP arrays until you understand them. Then come back and ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mixed up your nested arrays here. You need one cart array that contains one or more arrays of product_info. Just drop the call to array_push() and use this syntax:

```
if(!empty($this->cart)){
    // Add new product to array $this->cart
    $this->cart[] = $this->product_info);
} else {
    // Create Array with one product
    $this->cart = array($this->product_info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion helped me out alot appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any verification like if (empty) - this is PHP

$this->cart[] = $this->product_info;

so but if you use array_push you must do this verification  because array_push accept variable by reference and can't create or reassign it.